# Android fullscreen noactionbar change in the designer doesn't work

Tags: java, android, fullscreen

**Hello**

I have an annoying problem considering anroid apllication

When I select my theme in an android activity to `DeviceDefault.NoActionBar.Fullscreen` via designer, nothing happens. Here are the pictures:

[image: Activity]

Nothing changes in the output app, why?

[image: Output]

I'm using Android Studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Designer is not the place to set your theme permanently. Setting theme in Graphical Tool is only for preview purposes.

If you want to change your theme set it in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file for specific activity

`<activity android:theme="name_of_style_you_want_to_set">`